# opening a local folder browser from web browser

Tags: windows, vb.net

I know this shouldn't be as hard as I have found it to be, but I could use some help on a problem. I have used, and am familiar with the FileUpload control, works great.

But now I have a need to allow the user to choose a folder path without selecting a file. Basically a folder location, on the local hard drive where my code will read the files located in the choosen folder and process against them.

I am drawing a total blank and my web searches are not giving me what I am looking for.

I initially developed this with a Windows FolderDialogBrowser control, but it will not run on the web server, likely a security issue, and I can not change it.

```
Public Class FolderBrowserDialogExampleForm 
Inherits Form 

Private folderBrowserDialog1 As FolderBrowserDialog 
Private openFileDialog1 As OpenFileDialog 

Private richTextBox1 As RichTextBox 

Private mainMenu1 As MainMenu 
Private fileMenuItem As MenuItem 
Private WithEvents folderMenuItem As MenuItem, _ 
                   closeMenuItem As MenuItem, _ 
                   openMenuItem As MenuItem 

Private openFileName As String, folderName As String 

Private fileOpened As Boolean = False
```

Is there some way to open the folder browser on the local machine, from a web browser? I'm not looking to salvage the code above unless there is a reasonable fix.

Full error message:

```
Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'Form' is not defined.
```

Source error:

```
Line 10: 
Line 11: Public Class FolderBrowserDialogExampleForm
Line 12:     Inherits Form                             ' this line errors
Line 13: 
Line 14:     Private folderBrowserDialog1 As FolderBrowserDialog
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concept of folder selection in the HTML/JavaScript platform.  Even if you could select one, you wouldn't be able to do anything with the folder path.  If you use a plugin technology like Silverlight, Flash, or a Java applet, they may have folder selection and reading capabilities.

Comment: Well, I am not sure that is true. Here is another solution that I have recently found. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/krullfilesytembrowsing.aspx  and Microsoft has one in the MSDN library....http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog(v=VS.90).aspx        I'm just trying to get fixed what I have on the server without having to re-code much.

Comment: That first link would be helpful if you want to access the folder structure *of the web server* on the server, not the client; web applications do not have access to a client's file system.  The second link is for Windows forms; not all WinForms controls have WebForms equivalents.

Comment: My problem exactly. But your telling me other than the FileUpload control, there is no way to see the local folder path from a web bowser?  And why does it work on my DEV PC, regardless of the fact that web server and local PC are one in the same, the environment is still a web browser, right?

Comment: Even if you managed to get the folder path, you couldn't do anything with it.

Comment: Then I guess I am at a loss as to why this works on my DEV PC. I process hundreds of files within the choosen directory with no problem, writing data into an Access table from a gridview displayed on the web page.

Comment: You're able to do it in WinForms.  WinForms does not run within a browser; WebForms is just an abstraction layer around HTML/CSS/JavaScript.  If you can't do something client-side in pure HTML and JavaScript, you can't do it in WebForms either.  Web sites cannot process a client's folder.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Need to figure out a new direction I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The code that you are using is for windows forms, so it will not work in a web project. This is what the error messages are telling you.

If you want the user to select a directory on THEIR machine, then the standard File upload control will do the trick.

If you want the user to select a directory on the WEB server machine, then you will need to gather the list of folders that they can select from and present them to them in a Tree or other user interface construct that makes sense for the task you wish to perform.

Comment: I was hoping to only have the user select a folder on their local machine, without having to select a file.

Comment: Ah, I see your issue. This is unfortunately not available in straight HTML and, even if you managed to figure it out, you wouldn't be able to do anything with the files in that path due to security concerns. If you know the user base (i.e. it's not a general type of application), you could re-use your current form implementation in a ClickOnce app. Alternatively, you could create a silverlight applet loosely based on your current code.