# Is it possible to set folder path for input type IFormFile

Tags: asp.net-core, input, razor, bootstrap-5

I am currently working on a CMS web application. To select images i am using the following code. The input type is IFormFile(BigImage is of type IFormFile)

```
<div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-2 custom-file-button">
 <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupFile">GroßesBild</label>
 <input class="form-control" form="addUpdateSubmenu" asp-for="BigImage" id="inputGroupFile">
</div>
```

Now my question is if it is possible to set a default folder path like: **"\abc33\images\bilder"**
Now it is just opening any folder which was used the latest.

[So if i would select an image the directory would look like shown on this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3zh6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concept of folder selection in the HTML/JavaScript platform. Even if you could select one, you wouldn't be able to do anything with the folder path. `Web applications` **do not** have access to a client's file system.

Here is a similar issue, You can refer to [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056189/opening-a-local-folder-browser-from-web-browser).

Answer (score 0):

Browsers don't allow you to modify deafault file path(value)of`<input type="file"/>` due to security issue,the value only changes when you select a file yourself